# Convergence on smaller interval

Tags: real-analysis, weak-convergence

I have a following question:
let $f_n(x)$ be such that, $f_n\rightarrow f$ weakly in $L^2$, i.e. for all $g\in L^2$

$|\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f_n(x)-f(x))g(x)\,dx|\rightarrow 0$, with $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Let us take set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$. It is a regular set, let say some interval.
Do we know

$|\int_A(f_n(x)-f(x))g(x)\,dx|\rightarrow 0$?

Or maybe it is not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g':=g \times 1_A\in L^2$ for which $\left|\int (f_n-f)g'\right|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.